# Help using the C-S-B theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\Bbb R$ denote the set of real numbers.  Let $H\subseteq\Bbb R$ and assume that there are real numbers $a,b$ with $a>b$ such that the open interval $(a,b)$ is a subset of $S$. Prove that the cardinality of $H$ equals $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Let R denote the set of real numbers.  Let S⊆R and assume that ∃ real numbers x,y 
with x<y such that the open interval (x,y)  is a subset of S.  Prove that the cardinality of S equals c.

Comment: @Alex : It looks as if you hit the "save" button before you were done.  You can still edit the question further.

Comment: @user99680: The whole question was present in the source; for some reason it didn’t display correctly until I added the $\LaTeX$. Another user was having the same problem a few minutes ago.

Comment: There is a relatively-straightforward way of showing this using the $Atan:=tan^{-1}$ function. You do want Cantor-Bernstein, tho?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: No problem; sorry for my impatience.

Comment: @user99680: No problem: I’d have wondered the same thing if I hadn’t already seen that it was there but not displaying.

Comment: Yes the problem asks to use the cantor-schroder-bernstein theorem

Answer (score 1):

$w\mapsto x+ \dfrac{y-x}{1+2^w}$ is an injective mapping in one direction.

(As $w\to\infty$, this function goes to $x$; as $w\to-\infty$, this function goes to $y$; for other values of $w$, it's between $x$ and $y$.)

$v\mapsto v$ is an injective mapping in the other direction.

Comment: Are you assuming that $y>0$?

Comment: No the problem doesn't say anything about y>0

Comment: Typo: I had $y$ where I needed of course $y-x$.  Fixed.

Comment: Using $e$ as the base of the exponent is easier, because the derivative is slightly simpler to handle. Other than that, I totally agree that $\tan^{-1}$ is overused and overrated.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : I don't see why we need the derivative at all for this.

Comment: I didn't say that using arctan is overused or over-rated.  I just thought this was simpler because the image of $x\mapsto1/(1+2^x)$ is the interval from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Michael, it's an easy proof that the function is injective. But you are right, we generally don't need. As for the overrated, I said that. If you didn't agree with me, then consider the second part of my comment as talking to myself aloud. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use $\arctan:=\tan^{-1}$ for a map from $(-\pi/2, \pi/2) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ to inject, and , say, $f(x)=x$ in the other direction.